# Issues adding a student to a specific class in Microsoft Teams Graph API in python

Tags: python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, http-post

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyurS.png)

I am having issues with the format for my request body. Based on Microsoft Docs my request Body is supposed to "supply a JSON representation of an educationUser object". I have shown my code and the example given by Microsoft and I do not know what is wrong with my request body since it is the same format. Please help.
[microsoft example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TfUV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is better to include the code in question rather than as an external image.

Secondly, you have an authentication problem and the error is pretty specific about it - you have not supplied an Authentication header with your request.